# Delete single row from HABTM join table

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, delete-row

I've got model that use `ExtendAssociations`, but for some reason deleteHABTM doesn't seem to work on some models (no idea :/). Is there an easy way to just delete a single row from the join table?

Comment: You could try turning cascade on when deleting, as this should delete all related records also. Might be worth a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be some bad practice in cake.I suggest you check your [ExtendAssociations](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/add-delete-habtm-behavior) and make it work as you expected.

If you insist, there is an option called `deleteQuery` in [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).That may help you.